# create "Enter website" page

Tags: wordpress

i have a wordpress website, 
I have created html page with background and logo and "Enter website" Button
I want visitors to see this page first, and when click on "Enter website" button, they get redirected to the wordpress home ( which is in the same directory ) page.
Kindly note that this trick is different than the "wordpress static page"
I want to keep the wordpress index the same ( show the latest posts )
And want to show the intro page only once!
My idea was to upload the intro page with "index.html" name
And when you click enter, the link will be "index.php" so you see the wordpress default index.
but it failed, i don't know why, but when i go to index.php, i see the index.html content!!! not the wordpress one!
currently i am thinking about doing this trick through the template index file and the php sessions which is difficult.
Any one know a plugin or a simple way to do the trick?
Thankyou

Comment: To add a link to the homepage you just need to add:

    $url = home_url();
    echo esc_url( $url );

You can read more in here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/home_url

Comment: OT: Damn, is it 1999 again already …? (Because that’s when site authors thought such intro pages that have no real value whatsoever and just slow people down in getting access to the content they actually want would be a good idea … but most of the world has moved on since then.)

Comment: @CBroe You will understand why i want to do it, when you start working on valuable projects

Answer (score 0):

You can set landing page as index.html in root of your cpanel and then if any one click on button called Enter Website and then it will redirect to page called home that you have to create in wordpress admin (i.e. http://www.example.com/home).

Answer (score 0):

check this plugin

[WORDPRESS SPLASH PLUGIN](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-splash-page/)